# Sorting 3 Numbers from Least to Greatest

Tags: java, sorting

As part of a problem set I have to sort 3 numbers in ascending order. A simple enough task, but for some reason I'm not getting the expected result. Using arrays is not allowed. Below is my code; I've linked to my flowchart [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1841dhtn7lLHe6lgRl9UCpe8dEZOmCVQ6).  I cannot get the program to sort 3 numbers such as 5, 5, and -4. When I attempt that case, here is the output:

```
Enter three numbers.
```

In order -0.04 5.0 5.0In order 5.0 -0.04 5.0

If I get that one to work, I cannot get the case of 23, 0, 39 to sort. Not sure if I have over-complicated the attempt with so many cases; I feel that  my flowchart covers all possibilities. Thanks in advance!

```
  import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter three numbers.");

    double x = reader.nextDouble();
    double y = reader.nextDouble(); 
    double z = reader.nextDouble();

    if (x >= y){
            if (y >= z)
                System.out.print("In order " + z + " "+ y + " " + x);

            if  (z >= x)
                System.out.print("In order " + y + " "+ x + " " + z);

            if (x > z)
                System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + z + " " + x);
    }

    if (y > x)
    {
            if (z >= y)
                System.out.print("In order " + x + " " + y + " "+ z);
        if (z >= x)
            System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + x + " " + z);
        if (x > z)
            System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + z + " " + x);
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Do you wants to solve with if else statements or another way ?

Comment: Right now we're stuyding if and if/else statements and Boolean operators. That's all I can use as far as I know.

Comment: Be carefull when write code on logic. try with inputs and go on. @chsbellboy 's answer is right. He said what's wrong in ur code.

Comment: If you can, accept the most voted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve this with no `if`(s) using `Math.max(double, double)` and `Math.min(double, double)` and basic addition and subtraction. Like,

```
double max = Math.max(x, Math.max(y, z));
double min = Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z));
double mid = x + y + z - max - min;
System.out.printf("In order %f %f %f%n", min, mid, max);
```

Using `if` and `else` comparisons instead of `Math.max` and `Math.min` is a little more complicated. Pick a default value and compare with the other two. Like,

```
double max = z;
if (x > max || y > max) {
    if (x > y) {
        max = x;
    } else {
        max = y;
    }
}
double min = z;
if (x < min || y < min) {
    if (x < y) {
        min = x;
    } else {
        min = y;
    }
}

double mid = x + y + z - max - min;
System.out.printf("In order %f %f %f%n", min, mid, max);
```

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: That is great (I really want to see what the Math class does), and thanks for the help, but I'm supposed to use if and if/else statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with the if/else logic, here's a slight modification to your original solution.  Note the use of an else if. 
I have commented out your earlier lines of code for comparison.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter three numbers.");  //Use println instead of print, that way the input begins on the next line

    double x = reader.nextDouble();
    double y = reader.nextDouble(); 
    double z = reader.nextDouble();

    if (x >= y){ //In the three responses below, y is always before x.  
            if (y >= z)
                System.out.print("In order " + z + " "+ y + " " + x);

            else if  (z >= x)
                System.out.print("In order " + y + " "+ x + " " + z);

            else if (x > z)
                System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + z + " " + x);
    }

    if (y > x){// In the three responses below, x is always before y
        if (z >= y)
            System.out.print("In order " + x + " " + y + " "+ z);
        else if (z >= x)
            //System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + x + " " + z); //In this case, z has to be smaller than y.  The order was off
            System.out.print("In order " + x + " " + z + " " + y);
        else if (x > z)
            //System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + z + " " + x);
            System.out.print("In order " + z + " " + x + " " + y); //Y is the biggest.  The order here was off.  
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of using the "else if" statements...I think that's what I have flowcharted now that I look back at my paper. I am going to go back and look at how I got the order of my comparisons wrong. I thought I had that part correct, but now that I've read some of the responses I guess I missed that every time I tried to debug.

Comment: The comments are extremely helpful for me to see the difference between what I coded and what you corrected. Thank you very  much!

Comment: Regarding the comment to the first if statement, what do you mean? Are you citing an error, or are you stating a correction?

Comment: On the comment to the first if statement, it's not an error at all.  I'm just writing a brief explanation.  When I use flow charts, it's good to comment in the code the logic so that if I come back to that section of code I remember what I was thinking

Answer (score 3):

There is some issues with your `if/else` statements:

1. Use **else if** statements because either of the conditions will be true and not all and hence the result will be printed multiple times.
2. The second **if statement** the last two statements are wrong because if we enter that if statement then `(x < y)` for sure but you are printing `x` before `y` (now edited).

Here is the correct code:

```
if (x >= y) {
    if (y >= z)
        System.out.print("In order " + z + " " + y + " " + x);
    else if (z >= x)
        System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + x + " " + z);
    else if (x >= z)
        System.out.print("In order " + y + " " + z + " " + x);
} else {
    if (z >= y)
        System.out.print("In order " + x + " " + y + " " + z);
    else if (z >= x)
        System.out.print("In order " + x + " " + z + " " + y);
    else if (x >= z)
        System.out.print("In order " + z + " " + x + " " + y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the else statements were that important.  Regarding the output statements you mentioned, I see now what I did wrong...not sure how I missed that! .

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class a9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Input your numbers !!");

    int a = scan.nextInt();
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    int c = scan.nextInt();


    var ok =  Math.min(a , Math.min(b , c)); 
     
    if ( ok == a ) {
        if (c > b ) {
           System.out.println("Your order is : " + "," + c + "," + b + "," + a);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your order is : " + b + "," +  c + "," + a);
        }
    }
    else if (ok == b) {
        if( a > c) {
            System.out.println("Your order is : " + a + "," + c + "," + a);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your order is : " + c + "," + a + "," + b);
        }
    }

    else {
        if ( b > a) {
            System.out.println("Your order is : " + a + "," +  b + "," + c);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your order is : " + b + "," +  a + "," + c);
        }
    }
   

    
    
    
    
    scan.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I WANT TO MAKE A CORRECTION of the most upvoted answer by Elliot Frisch.

There is the need to first check if both conditions are true so we can store the correct 'max' and 'min' number.
Because on Elliot's answer this is not checked and if they are both true, the 'x' will always be the number that is stored, and that will sometimes give incorrect outputs.

HOPE IT HELPS :)

You can solve this with no `if`(s) using `Math.max(double, double)` and `Math.min(double, double)` and basic addition and subtraction. Like,

```
double max = Math.max(x, Math.max(y, z));
double min = Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z));
double mid = x + y + z - max - min;
System.out.printf("In order %f %f %f%n", min, mid, max);
```

Using `if` and `else` comparisons instead of `Math.max` and `Math.min` is a little more complicated. Pick a default value and compare with the other two. Like,

```
double max = z;
if (x > max && y > max) {
        if (x > y) {
            max = x;
        } else {
            max = y;
        }
}
if (x > max || y > max) {
    if (x > y) {
        max = x;
    } else {
        max = y;
    }
}
double min = z;
if (x < min && y < min) {
        if (x < y) {
            min = x;
        } else {
            min = y;
        }
}
if (x < min || y < min) {
    if (x < y) {
        min = x;
    } else {
        min = y;
    }
}

double mid = x + y + z - max - min;
System.out.printf("In order %f %f %f%n", min, mid, max);
```

Comment: The addition is useless. `x >max && y > max` does the same thing that is done by the next `if`, which is executed in that case. So nothing changes! Check this out on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/YK9bGh5xW). Sadly, the optimizer is not able to get rid of the useless addition (gcc).

Answer (score 0):

```
displaySortedNumbers(x, y, z)

public static void displaySortedNumbers(double num1, double num2, double num3) {

        double temp;
        if (num1 > num2) {
            temp = num2;
            num2 = num1;
            num1 = temp;
        }
        if (num1 > num3) {
            temp = num3;
            num3 = num1;
            num1 = temp;
        }
        if (num2 > num3) {
            temp = num3;
            num3 = num2;
            num2 = temp;
        }
        System.out.printf("Sorted numbers: %s, %s, %s", num1, num2, num3);
}
```